# How to model many-to-many through relationships in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I've read a lot of guides / best practices on how to model many-to-many relationship in DynamoDB single-table design, but I could not find a practical, hands-on guide on how to model a many-to-many "through" relationship.

Specifically, let's say that I got 3 entities: `Employees, Teams and Rules`

Relationships-wise, we assume that:

```
- Employees must follow many Rules that are specific for each employee (one-to-many).
- Teams must follow many Rules (many-to-many).
- Employees can be part of different Teams (many-to-many).
```

My main access pattern would be `Get all the Rules that an Employee should follow`, that means getting his specific rules as well as the rules he inherited by the Teams he's part of.

I started modelling the table structure like this:

| PK | SK | Attributes... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EMPLOYEE#one | METADATA |  |
| EMPLOYEE#one | RULE#one |  |
| EMPLOYEE#one | RULE#two |  |
| TEAM#one | RULE#three |  |
| TEAM#one | RULE#four |  |

With the idea of using reverse indexing to create the GSIs I needed to cope with my access patterns, But I hit a wall..

How can I model my data (single-table design) to efficiently retrieve all the rules that an Employee should follow?

I think I'd need to move the relationship between Employee and Teams on PK and SK, something like:

| PK | SK | Attributes... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... |  |  |
| EMPLOYEE#one | TEAM#one |  |
| ... |  |  |

But then I don't know how I could be able to build the correct indexes to retrieve all the infos I need..

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon DynamoDB documentation describes Many-to-Many Relationships here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

Comment: Appreciate, but I already knew almost by heart what's written in that page. I was asking for advices on this specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a composite Key con the SK that includes both Rules applied to Employees and Rules that are bonded to Teams. The final result is something like:

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| #EMPLOYEE_1 | #RULE_5 |
| #EMPLOYEE_1 | #TEAM_4#RULE_12 |
| #EMPLOYEE_1 | #TEAM_4#RULE_13 |

This should satisfy my access patterns.